# Bike trying to jumps gears when I stand

Tags: mountain-bike

My 2014 Norco storm 9.2 has a problem - whenever I am in a higher gear and standing up it tends to click and try to jump gears.

When I am sitting down it does not do this. It only happens when I stand.

Do you have any suggestions to help me?

Comment: Standing pedaling you mean or just standing?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean the rear derailleur jumps to a higher (harder to pedal) gear when you stand up to pedal hard, right?   This is a common rear derailleur problem, happens only  under high chain tensions, and more likely with inexpensive or worn rear derailleurs.  It shouldn't do that, as it can be dangerous to the rider.  So you need to get it fixed.    Your rear derailleur either needs an adjustment, or a replacement spring,  or you need to replace it with a new or better one.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the information provided: The frame is probably bending when you stand causing the chain to come out of alignment with the deraileurs and cassete/cogs.

I have a full suspension that can do that too when you pedal hard out of the seat.

Did you notice if it occurs in higher or lower gears and was the chain very tight? (will help narrow down the problem)

Comment: It happens in a higher gear and chain is kind of loose

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to check, before replacing any other parts, is whether the chain has stretched as a stretched chain could cause this problem.
Measure 12 links; each link should be precisely 1 inch. If the 12 links are 2-3mm longer (0.75 - 1%) than 12 inches the chain needs replaced.  When replacing a chain you will most likely need to replace the cassette (rear gears) as well as they will be worn to the same degree as the chain.